# How to apply ARRAYFORMULA together with COUNTIF in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to count how many Students choose "Yes" and how many Students choose "No". Each student will be given 5 rows, so the formula need to check whether any "Yes" or "No" exist in these 5 rows. Only count once even though there might be more than one "Yes" or "No" for one student.

Initially I'm using `COUNTIF(B2:B6,"Yes")` in column C and then use `COUNTIF(C2:C6,"<>0")` in column D. Finally, I use `COUNTIF(D2:D31,"<>0")` to obtain Number of student choose "Yes" or "No". I think it is to tedious to do it manually, is there any way can make this process simpler, maybe using `Arrayformula` or `Query` (Not sure how it can work together with `Countif`)? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(UNIQUE({IF(B2:B="",, 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)), B2:B}), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col2 is not null pivot Col2")))
```

[image]